# Proper way to listen to data changes, and update UI accordingly

Tags: android, observer-pattern

I'm storing numerical data (streamed from a Bluetooth connection running as a background `Service`) on a `static ArrayList`.
Every time my `List` is modified, I need to update my UI accordingly (which is a plot on an Activity).

I've read about:

- Implementing the [Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html) pattern interface
- Using [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)s

Which solution is the most appropriate? Is there any other better/simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set an `android.widget.Adapter` (perhaps a `BaseAdapter` or `ListAdapter` depending on your data) for the view to provide the data to the view. When the data is updated, simply call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method to update the view.